# Sorting algorithm, insertion sort

Tags: java, sorting, logic, median, insertion-sort

ive been trying to the  problem and have become stuck. The specification of the problem is a as follows

Median of k numbers is defined as the (k/2)th
 smallest number if k is even; and the ((k+1)/2)th
 smallest number if k is 
odd. For example, median of the 4 numbers: 2 1 8 7 is the 2nd smallest number i.e. 2, and the median of the 5 
numbers: 2 1 8 7 6 is the 3rd smallest number i.e. 6. 
In this problem, you'll be given N numbers. Let the kth
 median or m(k) be defined as the median of the first k 
numbers (1<=k<=N). i.e. the 5th
 median or m(5) is the median of the first 5 numbers, the 8th
 median or m(8) is the 
median of the first 8 numbers, etc. In other words, let Ai
 denote the ith
 number, then the kth
 median or m(k) is 
defined as the median of the numbers A1, A2, …, Ak. 
Your task is to find m(1) + m(2) + m(3) + ...+ m(n), output the sum modulo 100000

so basically you have to read in numbers, first number is stored in the variable N and dictates how many numbers to be read in after that point is. (this is always 5). Then you must iterate through the reading in of the numbers, storing them in array, then sorting them and then finding the median of the median and then store the value in the  and repeating until all numbers have been read in, sorted and median found.

I have managed to read the numbers in fine and i am able to sort them to some degree but my sorting algorithm, sorts them highest values first and smallest values last and in order to get the program to run properly to get the desired output i need it to be the other way round and i cant work out how.

The numbers read in will be like so

5

10

5

1

2

15

and the answer would be 27.

This is my code

Any help on this problem would be amazing because im just going round in cirles, btw the  System.out.println(myIntArray [4]) etc is just a tracer to see how the sorting is taking place

Comment: Why not simply use `Arrays.sort()`? Also, I don't think you should be sorting the entire array first. That will not get you the correct answer.

Comment: Ive been instructed to use an algorithm to sort it and not a java collection.

Comment: What i thought the code was doing was adding a value to the array and then sorting and then adding the next value from the list , is this not the case ?

Comment: Your sorting loop is `for (j = 1; j < myIntArray.length; j++)`. You should use `i` instead of `myIntArray.length` as the limit for `j`. `Arrays.sort` works on primitive arrays, not Java collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be sorting the entire array each time through. You need to sort from 0 to i (exclusive) at each iteration. Also, for odd length, you need parentheses when computing the subscript: `myIntArray[(i+1)/2]` instead of `myIntArray[i+1/2]`. Because of operator precedence, Java will evaluate the latter as `myIntArray[i+(1/2)]`, which is just `myIntArray[i]`, since `1/2` is 0 in integer division.

Comment: Thank you very much, you sorted my problem. The answer was correct after adding in the parentheses. Now its working out how to quicken the whole procedure to meet the time limitis